# i cant able to run the youtube videos in ios4.3

Tags: iphone, ipad, video

I have tried this following code to open youtube videos,its not working may i know the reason,

```
NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = @"<html><head>\
                      <body style=\"margin:0\">\
                      <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gczw0WRmHQU\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
                      width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
                      </body></html>";
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're loading that string into a webview, don't you?

```
    /**
 * Embeds the youtube HTML data into the webview
 */
- (void)embedYouTubeIntoWebview:(UIWebView *)webView 
                        withURL:(NSString *)url 
                        inFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  webView.delegate = self;
  NSString *embedHTML =
    @"\
  <html><head>\
  <style type=\"text/css\">\
  body {\
  background-color: transparent;\
  color: white;\
  }\
  </style>\
  </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
  <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
  width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
  </body></html>";
  NSString *html =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];

  [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
}
```

Remember that this won't work with the emulator. You need to test it in real device.